# How to change clicking behavior when double clicking on a mountable unit

Tags: 10.10, mount

When clicking on a mountable unit on the Desktop on Ubuntu 10.10 the first double click mounts the unit while the second one tells nautilus to show the user what is inside the mountable unit. I want to find out how to make it so a double click will do both, mount the unit and show it.

Comment: How did you get nautilus to show unmounted volumes on the desktop? :O

Comment: Good question. Maybe i need to be more specific. mountable units not like internal hard drives but externals and usb drives. They sometimes appear on the desktop BUT are not mounted yet. they just appear on the desktop without opening nautilus. With your comment am guessing this is a bug rather than a feature.

Comment: @CYREX: it's likely that the drives have something set to autorun.

Comment: @Roland - Can you explain further i did not understand sorry.

Comment: @CYREX: When a USB has autorun files sometimes it will show up on the desktop but it will not open until you force it to.

Comment: Yes that was the problem actually. Both devices, a usb i have and another external hard drive (The ones with the problem) had an autorun.inf with them. After removing it it works correctly. Thanks. The question should be closed or your answered put below just in case somebody gets the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a device has autorun files sometimes it will show up on the desktop, but it will not open until you force it to.

If you remove the autorun files it will work as normal.

Comment: Yeap. Solved ;)